# Xcode display random images instead of text from NSArray

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, arc4random

Hoping someone can help me make the following NSArray of text be an array of images that can randomize the random images instead of the current text. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@synthesize predictions = _predictions;

- (NSArray *) predictions {

    if (_predictions == nil){

        _predictions = [[NSArrayalloc] initWithObjects:
            @"Today",
            @"Tomorrow",
            @"Some other time", nil];
    }

    return_predictions;
}

- (NSString*) randomPrediction {
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.predictions.count);
    return [self.predictions objectAtIndex:random];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@synthesize predictions = _predictions;

- (NSArray *) predictions {

if (_predictions == nil){

    _predictions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"today.png",
        @"tomorrow.png",
        @"someothertime.png", nil];
}

return_predictions;
}
 - (NSString*) randomPrediction {
    int random = arc4random_uniform(self.predictions.count);
     return [self.predictions objectAtIndex:random];
}
```

And use of this....

```
UIImage myimage=[UIImage imageNamed:[self randomPrediction]];
```

That's it..I hope this answer will be helpful for you.Enjoy
Thanks,